# SQL, Find all entires that don't exist in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I've got two tables, A and B, I'm trying to find the values that exist in a column in table A that do not exist in a matching column in table B my current code is:

```
SELECT A.x
FROM A
WHERE A.x NOT IN (SELECT B.x FROM B);
```

I have also tried:

```
SELECT A.x
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS NOT (SELECT B.x FROM B);
```

But when i run the query, nothing is in the table, I know for a fact that there are values in the "x" column of A that are not in the "x" column of B, but there not showing up.

I have a feeling that I'm doing something extremely dumb, or missing the obviously obvious answer, but I'm to tired and I've been working on this for to long to care anymore, so cheers for any help =)

Comment: There's a match field between those tables? If yes, you can do a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You mean `NOT EXISTS` (not `EXISTS NOT`)?

Comment: Your first query should work. The second one is missing `WHERE` (and is probably syntactically incorrect, unless `EXISTS NOT` is something MS Access specific that I'm not aware of).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using an `OUTER JOIN`?

```
SELECT A.x
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
WHERE B.x IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Could there be a `null` value in `B.x`?  If so, the `not in` reads like:

```
a.x not in (1, 2, 3, null, ...)
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
a.x <> 1 and a.x <> 2 and a.x <> 3 and a.x <> null and ...
```

Because `anything <> null` evaluates to `unknown`, the `not in` condition is never true.  The result is an empty rowset. It's an unpleasant side effect of three valued logic that catches even experienced SQL developers by surprise.

One solution is to exclude the `null` value, like:

```
SELECT x FROM A WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT x FROM B where x is not null)
```

For more details, see [the Wikidia article on three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Comment: No, there no null entries that i can see

Comment: I bet there are. Just try: `SELECT x FROM B WHERE x IS NULL`